# Ag-grid React: How to disable row group collapse

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have an ag-grid where rows are grouped by first column. The group are expanded by default. I want to disable group collapse on click.

```
colDefs = [{
    field: 'colA',
    rowGroup: true,
    hide: true
}, {
   field: 'colB'
}, 
...
];

gridOptions = {
   groupDefaultExpanded: -1,
   ...
}
```

How do i prevent from collapsing the group open by default

Answer (score 2):

I guess the colB has a showRowGroup: 'colA' and a cellRenderer: 'agGroupCellRenderer'.
You can remove the cellRenderer from it and it will display the group title as a simple string without showing the collapse icon and without the collapse abililty too.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do that by adding the following CSS:

```css
.ag-group-expanded { pointer-events: none; }
```

I also set on the `cellRendererParams`:

```js
cellRendererParams: {
  ...,
  suppressDoubleClickExpand: true,
  suppressEnterExpand: true,
}
```

So there is no way to collapse the rows.